# install_github install package but I can't call the functions

Tags: r, github, devtools, roxygen2

I can see my package is installed with `library()`, but when I load the package from the library, I can't call any of the functions.

```
> install_github("pdfHarvester", "hansthompson")
> library(pdfHarvester)
> Convert
Error: object 'Convert' not found
> Parse_Tables
Error: object 'Convert' not found
```

Comment: its just a custom function from my package.  It converts pdfs to page images

Comment: Make sure you run `document()` or `roxygenize()` after making changes to the roxygen code.

Comment: Side note: You should read up on using imports/depends.  Making calls to require or library inside of your functions is not the proper way to load packages from within a package.

Comment: thanks. I'm aware and that is a priority of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you package actually exports the functions you want to use.  This is a package development issue - not an issue with install_github.

Note that your NAMESPACE file is empty: https://github.com/hansthompson/pdfHarvester/blob/master/NAMESPACE

It looks like you're using roxygen for your .R files.  If you're using devtools for the package creation you need to use `document()` to generate your help file and populate the NAMESPACE file.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `document(pkg)` as the necessary step to populate the `NAMESPACE` and help files.

Comment: True - I added that as a comment to the question but it would be worth mentioning in the answer.